# Calculate: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\frac{x^k}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, exponential-function

Find the following sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

where $x$ is a real number. This is a power series in $x$. In particular, I'm interested in the case $x>0$.

This is very similar to [Calculate: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\frac{x^k}{k!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2005837/10063), the only difference being the $k$ isn't squared in the denominator.

**Disclaimer:** This is not a homework exercise, I do not know if a closed form solution exists. If it doesn't, exist, then an approximation in terms of well-known functions (not the all-mighty general hypergeometric $_pF_q$, something simpler please) would be desired.

Comment: WRA says a closed form exists: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x%5Ek%2F(k(k!))+from+k%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: How do the answers to your other question not directly answer this one? You can use exactly the same methods.

Comment: It is clearly a hypergeometric function by the structure of its coefficients. And it is clearly an exponential integral, too.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki As the answers here show, this sum turns out to be simpler than the one with the squared $k$. Over there the only choice seems to be an $_3F_3$.

Comment: @becko I'm not saying the answers are the same - I'm saying the techniques are exactly the same, and you should be able to use the answers to the other question to straightforwardly answer this one. I'm just a little confused as to what the purpose of this question was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have 
$$e^{x}-1=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{k}}{k!}}$$
$$\frac{e^{x}-1}{x}=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{k-1}}{k!}}$$

integrate both sides from $x=0$ to $x$
$$\int_{0}^{x}(\frac{e^{x}-1}{x})dx=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{k}}{kk!}}$$

so
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{k}}{kk!}}=\int_{0}^{x}(\frac{e^{x}-1}{x})dx$$
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{k}}{kk!}}=Ei(x)-\log(x)-\gamma$$

Comment: (proving you can't get a closed-form, since [$Ei(x)$ is a special function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral))

Answer (score 4):

Put $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \frac{x^k}{k!}.$$ Then $$f'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!} = \frac{1}{x}\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{x^k}{k!} = \frac{e^x - 1}{x}.$$ Since $f(0) = 0$, we then get $$f(x) = \int^x_0 \frac{e^t - 1}{t} dt.$$ I'm fairly certain this is the best you'll get without resorting to special functions.