# Closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k+1)^4 k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

A graduate student in physics asked me if there was a closed form for the following series, which he had found as the second virial coefficient for a gas in an exponential potential: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k+1)^4 k!}$$ where $x < 0$. This is the generalized hypergeometric function $_4 F_4(1, 1, 1, 1; 2, 2, 2, 2; x)$ by definition. We were skeptical that it could be simplified, as neither the series nor any of its first few derivatives and antiderivatives is the Taylor series of a function that we could recognize. Even if there's not a truly closed form, we're still curious whether it has a formula with special functions other than the generalized hypergeometric.

Comment: the site suggested an analogous https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005837/calculate-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k2-fracxkk?rq=1 im not too optimistic of a more closed form then

Comment: Even better, look for the commentary on the first answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006799/calculate-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k-fracxkk?rq=1

Comment: The given series equals $$-\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}e^{xy}\log^3(y)\,dy$$ so its asymptotic behaviour is pretty simple to estimate, but a nice closed form... I won't bet on that.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I don't immediately see where that integral comes from; can you give a justification?

Comment: @ConnorHarris: $$\frac{1}{(k+1)^4}=-\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}y^k\log^3(y)\,dy,$$ hence by multiplying both sides by $\frac{x^k}{k!}$ and summing over $k\geq 0$ we get the previous integral representation.

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote
\begin{equation}
S_q(x) := \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k+1)^q k!} 
\end{equation}
and $y=-x$.

Using JackD'Azurio's integral representation we get:
\begin{eqnarray}
S_4(x) &=& -\frac{1}{3!}\left. \frac{d^3}{d \theta^3} \int\limits_0^1 e^{x y} y^\theta dy \right|_{\theta=0} \\
&=&-\frac{1}{3!} \left. \frac{d^3}{d \theta^3} \frac{\Gamma(1+\theta) - \Gamma(1+\theta,-x)}{(-x)^{1+\theta}} \right|_{\theta=0} \\
&=&
\frac{4 \zeta(3)+2 \gamma^3+ \gamma \pi^2+(6 \gamma^2+\pi^2)\log(y)+6 \gamma \log(y)^2+2 \log(y)^3+12 {\mathfrak f}(y)}{12 y}
\end{eqnarray}
where 
\begin{equation}
{\mathfrak f}(y) := \int\limits_1^\infty \frac{e^{-y t}}{t} \frac{\log(t)^2}{2!} dt =
G_{3,4}^{4,0}\left(y\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1 \\
 0,0,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)
\end{equation}
where the function above is expressed through the Meijer-G function and $\gamma$ is the Euler's gamma constant.