# Evaluate the limit of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Evaluate the limit of:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}$$

Hints I am given:

1- The exponential series of type $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ converge into $e^x$ for any $x\in R$

2- Any series of type $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{P(n)}{n!}x^n$ , being $P(n)$ a polynomial of any level and $\forall x\in R$, it also converges.

3- $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$

**What is the limit of this series?**

According to the hints it is convergent, this is what I tried so far:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$

Applying hint 3:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{n!}$

Split the series in 2:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$

Applying hint 1, with $x=1$ to the second part:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{n!}=e+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}$

I dont know how to keep going, I know that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}$ converges into $e$ therefore the result of the whole series is 2 times $e$ **but I dont understand why!**

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{m!}=e.$$

Comment: Additionally, "the limit of $\sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)$" is redundant since $\sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)$ is already a limit, $\lim_{N\to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(n)$. So "the limit of $\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(n)$ as $N\to +\infty$" or just "$\sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)$".

Comment: Note that $n^2=n(n-1)+n$ - that's how I would begin this. (Polynomials in $n$ can be expressed in a similar way)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711318/show-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-2-mathrme/1711325#1711325

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^2}{k!}$

Writing $k! = k(k-1)!$, we get

$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{(k-1)!} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k-1}{(k-1)!} +\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(k-1)!}$.

Using $(k-1)! = (k-1)(k-2)!$, this can be further simplified to:

$S_n = \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{(k-2)!} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(k-1)!}$.

Each of the above summations converges to $e$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, so we get $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_n = 2e$.

Comment: You go from $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{(n-1)!}$ to $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-2)!}$ and change the summation's first item to 2, why can you do this?

Comment: @user605734MBS, because ${n-1\over(n-1)!}=0$ for $n=1$ and $1\over(n-2)!$ for $n\ge2$.

Comment: It's because the first term of the summation is 0 ($\frac{n-1}{(n-1)!} = 0$ for $n=1$), so changing the starting index to 2 won't make a difference.

Comment: Okay I'll make sure to change the index first from now on, I was stuck there because I simplified first and then tried to change the inex, but I got $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-2)!}$ then the first item would be $\frac{1}{(-1)!}$ Which is undefined.

Comment: $S_n$ is not a function of $n$.

Comment: @martycohen Edited my answer. Better?

Answer (score 5):

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2 x^n}{n!}
$$
can be expressed as
$$
f(x) = x \frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}e^x\right) = x \frac{d}{dx}(xe^x) = e^x(x+x^2).
$$
Therefore your sum is $f(1)=2e$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{matrix}
\\&\dfrac1{0!}&+&\dfrac1{1!}&+&\dfrac1{2!}&+&\dfrac1{3!}&+&\dfrac1{4!}&+&\cdots
\\+&&&\dfrac1{0!}&+&\dfrac1{1!}&+&\dfrac1{2!}&+&\dfrac1{3!}&+&\cdots
\\\hline
=&\dfrac1{0!}&+&\dfrac{1+1}{1!}&+&\dfrac{1+2}{2!}&+&\dfrac{1+3}{3!}&+&\dfrac{1+4}{4!}&+&\cdots
\\=&\dfrac1{0!}&+&\dfrac{2}{1!}&+&\dfrac{3}{2!}&+&\dfrac{4}{3!}&+&\dfrac{5}{4!}&+&\cdots
\\=&\dfrac{1^2}{1!}&+&\dfrac{2^2}{2!}&+&\dfrac{3^2}{3!}&+&\dfrac{4^2}{4!}&+&\dfrac{5^2}{5!}&+&\cdots
\end{matrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n^2}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{(n+1)}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n!}=$$$$=\sum_{n=0}^{N-2}\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n!} \to e+e=2e$$

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
differentiate it
$$e^{x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}$$
multiply by $x$
$$xe^{x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{nx^{n}}{n!}$$
differentiate it again
$$xe^{x}+e^x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n^2x^{n-1}}{n!}$$
let $x=1$
$$1e^{1}+e^1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n^2}{n!}$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n^2}{n!}=2e$$

Answer (score 1):

If
$S_k
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{n^k}{n!}
$,
then
$S_0 =e-1$
and,
for $k \ge 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
S_{k+1}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{n^{k}}{(n-1)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(n+1)^{k}}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n!}(n+1)^{k}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n!}\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}n^j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{n^j}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n!}+\sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{n^j}{n!}\\
&=e+\sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{n^j}{n!}\\
&=e+\sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j}S_j\\
\end{array}
$

Setting
$k=0$,
$S_1 = e$.

Setting
$k=1$,
$S_2 = e+S_1
=2e$.

Setting
$k=2$,
$S_3 = e+2S_1+S_2
=5e$.

If
$S_k =et_k$
then
$t_1  = 1$
and
$t_k
=1+\sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j}t_j
$.

The first few 
$t_k$
are
$1, 2, 5$
and these turn out to be
the well-studied
Bell numbers -
see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number
for a reasonable discussion.