# Sum of series involving factorials and number e

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider $\sum \frac{n^2}{n!}$. How can I find the sum? My attemp: it is equal to $\sum \frac{n}{(n-1)!}$, and we know that $\sum \frac{1}{n!}=e$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2979659/evaluate-the-limit-of-sum-n-1-infty-fracn2n?noredirect=1

Comment: You're halfway there.  Now, notice that $n=1+(n-1)$ and split up the fractions into something more manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$. If you differentiate wrt $x$ on both sides you'd get
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}\iff xe^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx^n}{n!}$$
If we differentiate once again, we get this
$$(x+1)e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2x^{n-1}}{n!}$$
Finally, evaluating the equation at $x=1$, you get that the series you asked for is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n!}=2e,$$
where we changed the starting index to $1$ because the $n=0$ term vanishes due to the $n^2$ in the summand.