# Prove $\int xe^xdx=(x-1)e^x+C$ using summation (no integration by parts)

Tags: integration, summation

So I have the integral $\int xe^xdx$ , which is very easy to solve but I was wondering if its answer could b proven using summations for $e^x$. I have got up to the point below but I am unable to evaluate the final summations:
$$\int xe^xdx=\int x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)n!}$$
now I know that:
$$(n+2)n!=\frac{(n+2)!}{n+1}$$
so we can rewrite:
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$$
now I don't know how to evaluate these summations, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

as others have suggested using $k=n+2$ as a substitution I will try this:
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^!}-\sum_{k=0}^1\frac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}+e^x-(1+x)$$

EDIT 2:

as @lab bhattacharjee suggested,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{[(n+2)-1]x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x.\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}-\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$$
and this is much easier to evaluate

Comment: Try k = n+2 in your sums. Some things will become clearer :)

Comment: The interchange of integral and infinite summation takes more proof than integration by parts...

Comment: In most contexts its clear that they are interchangeable though because $\int [f(x)+g(x)]dx=\int f(x)dx+\int g(x)dx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)\cdot n!}$$

$$=(n+1)\cdot\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$$

$$=\dfrac{\{(n+2)-1\}x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$$

$$=x\cdot\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}-\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$$

Comment: @b00n, I was editing it :)

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581603/evaluate-frac13-frac14-frac12-frac15-frac13-dots

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

The second summation is just $e^x-x-1$ (do the substitution $n+2=k$)

For the first summation use that $\displaystyle(\sum x^n)'=\sum nx^{n-1}$