# Limit of a series containing factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The series is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{(k+1)!}$.
I can only deal with those which can be transformed into definite integral and those which have a explicit formula of summation.
Any hint towards this one would be appreciated!

Comment: Telescoping series.

Comment: $$\frac{k+1-1}{(k+1)!}=\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581603/evaluate-frac13-frac14-frac12-frac15-frac13-dots    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44113/whats-the-value-of-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frack2k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(k+1)-1}{(k+1)!}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left[\frac{k+1}{(k+1)!}-\frac1{(k+1)!}\right].$$
Can you now finish off?